# CSS: Opacity make display object go under other objects

Tags: html, css, xhtml

My menu elements supposed to be on top of the image. Like this

[image: before]

```
<div class="menu">...</div>
<img src="..."/>
```

However when I add opacity to the style of the image, the menu elements lay under the image

[image: after]

```
<div class="menu">...</div>
<img src="..." style="opacity:0.9"/>
```

Does anyone know what's going on and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce a demo on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar? Ideally [SSCCE (short, self-contained, correct example)](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Yes, what happens if you apply `opacity:1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet would be the opacity is giving a z-index to the image. Have you tried adjusting the z-index on the menu?

Comment: Yes. Opacity was messing up the z-index ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem. Adjust z-index. Remember z-index only works with **positioned** (absolute, relative, etc..) elements

do the following

```
<div class="menu" style="position: relative; z-index:100000;"></div>
<img src="..." style="position: relative; opacity:0.9; z-index:-1;"/>
```

Thanks